# Why do people tend to store NSURL as NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

All over the internet as well as here on SO, I see code similar to this

```
NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
```

and then

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageUrl];
```

Why not just store the NSURL? is it because of optimization? Is NSString that less expensive to store?

Comment: Store it where? Where are these two lines of code? In separate places or the same method?

Comment: Anyone using the 1st line of code is crazy. It could break at any time. The proper way to convert an `NSURL` to an `NSString` is by using the `absoluteString` method, NOT with `stringWithFormst:`.

Comment: Bad habits. A URL or URI is structured data, and NSURL expresses that. A string is an array of characters.

Comment: @rmaddy they are not in the same place. I am thinking of putting them in a job-queue so the image can be sent even without network (i.e. store the url until there is network).

Comment: @KatedralPillon Then keep the original `NSURL`. There is no reason to convert the `NSURL` to an `NSString` unless you actually have a need to use an `NSString` representation of the URL.

Comment: @quellish are you saying there should not be a need to convert?

Comment: No, I am saying a URL is a URL. NSURL represents URLs. NSURLComponents provides an interface for mutating (changing) URLs. URLs should not be represented as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the time, it doesn't seem to be an issue of space (storing an `NSString` would be more efficient if the `NSURL` wouldn't contain any other specific data, but not to the point of making a difference in most applications).

Really, the most common reason for storing a URL as string is that it's the way we think of URLs ourselves—simply strings.

In the end, the most applicable/specific choice is generally best—`NSURL` represents "a URL that can potentially contain the location of a resource on a remote server, the path of a local file on disk, or even an arbitrary piece of encoded data" ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)), while an `NSString` simply represents a string of text—if a URL is what you're going for, use `NSURL`.

(One clear upside to `NSString`'s is that they're more portable—but `NSURL` can be serialized and moved about if needed, too!).

Answer (score 1):

NSString is more universally used. For example, AFNetworking uses strings instead of NSURLs. Also, if you need to send this URL to a web server as a parameter you will need it in string format as well.

Lazy instantiation is just a good practice in Obj-C. Create the objects only when you need them.